# How to use AsyncTask with double parameters in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, double

I want to get two `double` values by using an `asynctask` class and should show the `progress-dialog` during this time how do i do that someone please help me to do this and give me some example links on this topic..

here is my **code**

```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<double, int, double>{

        private Activity activity;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        private double lon;
        private double lat;

public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, double longitude, double latitute) {
            super();
this.activity = activity;
this.lon = longitude;
this.lat = latitute;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
}

protected double doInBackground(double... v) {
//do your stuff here
    if(lat==0.0&&lon==0.0)
return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
task.execute();
Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

Comment: Do you want the return value of AsyncTask to contain two doubles?

Comment: what do you mean by "get two double"

Comment: @agent451 just post your code and i'll surely try to help

Comment: any method can not return two values... you will have to implement your own logic

Comment: inside this asynctask class i plan to get latitude and longitude

Comment: just make your return value of AsyncTask to be Double[]

Comment: What i meant is I want to pass two double values to the doinbackground() and do some operation from there and using location manager class want to retrieve latitude and longitude. simply i am trying to get gps location inside this asynctask class..

Comment: make your generic types double wrapper array like this AsyncTask<Double[], int, Double[]> with this way you can take multiple double values for doInBackground method and also can return multiple double values from there and thus onPostExecute() method also take multiple double values

Comment: You can't use primitive data types as you declared in `AsyncTask<double, int, double>`. Make sure you use their respective wrapper classes this way: `AsyncTask<Double, Integer, Double>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass as many doubles as you want.

`asyncTask.execute(double1, double2);`

And then inside Async Task you can access them doing something like:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Integer, Result> {
     Result result=null;
     protected Result doInBackground(Double... doubles) {
         // Getting your doubles
         double1 = doubles[0];
         double2 = doubles[1];

         // Triggers the execution of onProgressUpdate()
         publishProgress((int) double1);

         result = new Result();
         result.setLat(/*Your lat value.*/);
         result.setLon(/*Your lon value.*/);
         return result;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // Update your UI with the current progress.
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
         Double lat = result.getLatitude();
         Double lon = result.getLongitude();

         // Do anything after doInBackground() is completed
     }
 }
```

Let me know if this what you wanted.

***EDIT:***

```
class Result {
public lat;
public lon;

public Result(){
}

// Your getters and setters will be declared here.
}
```

Comment: i want to pass integer value to progressupdate and at last i want to get latitude and loingitude inside onpostexecute as double

Comment: @agen451, look to the update. I think you can't pass 2 results to the `onPostExecute` method. Try to pass them inside a double array or other way.

Comment: Yes, of course. I guess `Result` will be an object instance of some class you create, right?

Comment: but how do i do that can you help me with result?

Comment: @agen451, Take a look at my edit. You could do it that way! (If it's a good or bad way that's another discussion :)) You just have to handle `sets` and `gets` and thats all...

Comment: i am using your code but i couldn't use the latitude and longitude that got from the doinbackground please fix this too any way thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass it this way..

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

public MyAsyncTask(int number) {
    super();
    // do stuff
}

// doInBackground() 
// onPostExecute(), ect

}
```

Call this like how you call any other class..

```
new MyAsyncTask(number).execute(maybe_other_params);
```